# Help me identify what this plant is?

Tags: identification

It is similar to the wandering Jew. Has reddish purple color leaves on the back of the leaves. Turn's upwards at end as if to be a climber.

[image: Unknown Plant]

What plant is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKT9Y.jpg)similar)?

Comment: Sure looks like a wandering jew to me.  Some are even more mind boggling reddish purple, too.  That plant needs more sun.  Get it closer to a window, not in direct sunlight but you could hang it very near and get it used to more sunlight.  Sunlight and chemicals in the soil is what plants have to have to make food for themselves.  Otherwise, they die slowly.  During the summer I always take my indoor plants outside on a covered porch, no acclimation involved so they are able to get as much light as possible to withstand the dark winters.  Otherwise they are long term perishables.

Comment: This appears to be Purple Heart, *Tradescantia pallida*

Answer (score 2):

Sure looks like a wandering jew to me. Some are even more mind boggling reddish purple, too. That plant needs more sun. Get it closer to a window, not in direct sunlight but you could hang it very near and get it used to more sunlight. Sunlight and chemicals in the soil is what plants have to have to make food for themselves. Otherwise, they die slowly. During the summer I always take my indoor plants outside on a covered porch, no acclimation involved so they are able to get as much light as possible to withstand the dark winters. Otherwise they are long term perishables.  How long have you had this plant?  If it is recent it is probably still using chemicals applied by the nursery.  So no fertilization for at least a month.  Get Osmocote 14-14-14, follow directions.  Give no more at all until a good 3 to 4 months have passed.  In half a year a larger pot would be in order and please only use plain potting soil.  Does this answer your question?